# getAbsolutePath ignoring certain folders

Tags: java, filepath

My problem is that `getAbsolutePath` is ignoring certain folders around the file that I'm trying to find. What I'm trying to do is get the filepath of a file only using its name. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File file = new File("Point.java");
        String path = file.getCanonicalPath();

        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(path));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("not work");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: /Users/default/Desktop/Eclipse/TreeThing/Point.java doesn't exist.
at java.awt.Desktop.checkFileValidation(Desktop.java:210)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:270)
at ForkBomb.main(ForkBomb.java:11)
```

The real filepath is `/Users/default/Desktop/Eclipse/TreeThing/src/Point.java`, but because the directory src is being ignored the program won't run. How can I solve it?

Comment: It's being opened relative to the current working directory, which evidently is `TreeThing`, not `TreeThing/src`.

Comment: I traced the filepath myself and it is inside a folder called src, which is inside TreeThing.

Comment: Maybe you should read the javadoc of [`getCanonicalPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath--) again (or for the first time?) so see what it *actually* does. Hint: It is *not* a file *search* method.

Comment: Java is not a scripting language. You are not literally running the source file.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are running your code from the /Users/default/Desktop/Eclipse/TreeThing directory. This sets the 'current working directory' for your application.

So when you instantiate a `File` object without a path, the code assumes it is in the current working directory.

It does **not** perform a search for you.

If you want to refer to the existing Point.java, use either:

```
File file = new File("src/Point.java");
```

... or:

```
File file = new File("/Users/default/Desktop/Eclipse/TreeThing/src/Point.java");
```